# User Profile Import - more than on Search Base

Tags: sharepoint

In AD we have these two OUs:

- OU=Accounts - Standard User
- OU=Accounts - Restricted User

The Search base in the connection for our user profile import contains this:

- OU=Accounts - Standard User,DC=in,DC=company,DC=com

The import works great for this single OU.

I tried making a second connection but SharePoint will not allow multiple connections to the same domain.

**How do I configure the import/connection to pull from both OUs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the search base up to the level above both OU's, then change your filter so that it only pulls User AD objects with certain fields set. For instance, this filter will get all user objects with both the first name and last name fields set to something:

```
(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(givenName=*)(sn=*))
```